# AWS Elasticsearch Kibana Plugin Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I've got an Elasticsearch cluster hosted in AWS, which currently has open permissions.

I'm looking to lock that down to only being accessible from the AWS account in which it lives, however if I do this (with a `Principal` statement in the Elasticsearch access policy) then I can no longer use the AWS-provided Kibana plugin - it fails saying that the anonymous user cannot perform ESHttpGet.

I can find lots of questions on how to link a self-hosted Kibana to an AWS Elasticsearch, but not the provided one. Can anyone help with what access I need to allow for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I found this section in an [AWS documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-kibana.html):

> Because Kibana is a JavaScript application, requests originate from the user's IP address. IP-based access control might be impractical due to the sheer number of IP addresses you would need to whitelist in order for each user to have access to Kibana. One workaround is to place a proxy server between Kibana and Amazon ES. Then you can add an IP-based access policy that allows requests from only one IP address, the proxy's. The following diagram shows this configuration.

So the solution is to also whitelist any IP addresses from which you'd like to be able to use Kibana.